# How to call methods in Vue app $refs.components or Vuex $store from registerServiceWorker.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, scope, service-worker

I'm working on a Vue PWA scaffolded out with Vue CLI, which by default uses `register-service-worker` package to expose the serviceWorker lifecycle methods in `registerServiceWorker.js`:

```js
ready () {
  console.log(
    'App is being served from cache by a service worker.'
  )
},
registered () {
  console.log('Service worker has been registered.')
},
cached () {
  console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
},
updatefound () {
  console.log('New content is downloading.')
},
updated () {
  console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
},
offline () {
  console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.')
},
error (error) {
  console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
}
```

`registerServiceWorker.js` is imported into `main.js`:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/index'
import './registerServiceWorker'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

The question is, how do I access scope to call methods in my Vuex $store or App.vue $refs.components from the scope of `registerServiceWorker.js`, e.g.

```js
updated () {
  // Something like
  this.$store.commit('showUpdateNotification')
  // OR
  this.$refs.updateNotification.show()
}
```

I know I can setup additional eventListeners in my app to do this, but seems better to make use of `registerServiceWorker.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the Vuex store in your `registerServiceWorker.js` file.

ie.

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */

import { register } from 'register-service-worker'
import appConfig from './app.config.json'
import store from './store'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  register(`${appConfig.router.baseUrl}service-worker.js`, {
    ready() {
      console.log(
        'App is being served from cache by a service worker.'
      )
    },
    cached() {
      console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
    },
    updated() {
      console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
      store.commit('showUpdateNotification')
    },
    offline() {
      console.log(
        'No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode.'
      )
    },
    error(error) {
      console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
    },
  })
}
```